# How to separate directories from files, then sort them?

Tags: php

ilesI am working on a little file manager. I have an associative array of files and directories like this:

```
$files = array(
    array("name1", "size1", "date1", "type1"),
    array("name2", "size2", "date2", "type2")
);
```

Now, what I need to do is sort that array. First I would like to separate directories from folders, as they have a different "type" value in that array. Directories are represented with "dir", files with "file". After I separate those two, I'd like to order them by either name, size, or date (timestamp), ascending or descending.

Can anyone give me an idea how to do this?

Comment: Use [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort).

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
   if ($file[3] == 'dir') { ... it's a dir ... }
   if ($file[3] == 'file') { ... it's a ... any guesses? ...}
}
```

what's the difference between a "folder" and a "directory"?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

You can use these two functions in your loop to determine whether the file in question is a file or a directory.